# CSS/JavaScript: get user-visible text of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, innerhtml

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <span style="display:inline;">foo</span>
  <span style="display:none;">bar</span>
  <span style="display:inline;">baz</span>
</div>
```

.. is there some way in JavaScript for me to get the output "foo baz" (not "foo bar baz")?

`$('test').textContent` returns the latter, and `innerHTML` does the equivalent.

I don't care at all if the method used is hackish or roundabout, and can deal with it if it's browser-specific or requires Flash.

However, it must not require anything other than JS or Flash, it must not require any user interaction, and it must not return 'bar'.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, but note it won't have a space like your example, because there is no space in the markup:

```
$("#test :visible").text()
```

Here's an alternative, like your example spaced out for each span:

```
var s = new Array();
$("#test :visible").each(function() {
   s.push($(this).text());
});
alert(s.join(' '));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. PERFECT.

I don't need to do your Array addition, since I can just add a space to the inside of each anchor tag's text.

One thing to note: your method requires jQuery.

Comment: PS Implemented and thanked: http://cssfingerprint.com :)

In Safari, this method is 4x faster than my previous one. In Firefox, it's not an improvement. Still worthwhile. Thanks!